# Как установить библиотеку Xgboost на Windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, машинное-обучение

Пробовал по инструкции на [хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/273363/), но не нашел в репозитории папку xgboost/windows, нет её.
Пробовал как [здесь](https://inlovewithcode.wordpress.com/2015/08/26/how-to-install-xgboost-in-python/) через MinGW-w64, дальше make не получается. 
Помогите, пожалуйста, кто сталкивался.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объяснение такое:

- Статья на Хабре прошлогодняя, поэтому внезапно устарела,
- А уже в этом году признано, что проект для Windows неактуален (см. https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/736), поэтому планируется полный переход на CMake (ещё про это здесь: https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/792).
- Ещё в середине января всё для Windows убрано из репозитория.

Пока всё не утряслось, можно взять старую версию репозитория, в которой .sln для Windows ещё есть. По ссылкам выше видно, на какие ревизии ориентироваться.

Но самое надёжное - воспользоваться инструкцией https://xgboost.readthedocs.org/en/latest/build.html#building-on-windows (по ссылке https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/831 виден один нюанс с командой `mkdir`, а в остальном должно всё работать).

**Дополнение:**

Привожу сокращённый перевод руководства с официального сайта:

Сперва надо клонировать репозиторий xgboost. Откройте git-shell и выполните следующие команды:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
```

После установке [Git для Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/), запустите `Git Bash`. Все следующие шаги выполняются в нём:

В MinGW для выполнения `make` надо позвать `mingw32-make`, поэтому стоит добавить следующую строчку в файл `.bashrc`:

```
alias make='mingw32-make'
```

Чтобы собрать xgboost в MinGW выполните следующую команду:

```
cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk; make -j4
```

**Дополнение 2:**

Ответ на вопрос о том, как открыть git-shell:

Если установлен [GitHub для Windows](http://windows.github.com/), то должен был быть создан такой ярлык. Если его нет (удалили почему-то), то можно запустить git-shell одной из этих команд (зависит от версии, не забудьте вставить правильный `Username`):

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell
```

или

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\GitHub\GitHub.appref-ms --open-shell
```

Открыв git-shell одной из этих команд, восстановите нужные ярлыки, выполнив команду

```
github --reinstall-shortcuts
```

Comment: Спасибо, прояснили вопрос с этой библиотекой. Попробовал скачать версию 0.4.7, но собрать не получается, жалуется на отсутствие xgboostjavawrapper (load failed).  Не могли бы Вы расписать поподробнее?

Comment: Судя по всему, Вы использовали VS2015. Можно или более старой студией скомпилировать, или всё же пойти по современному пути, который уже у многих получился: https://xgboost.readthedocs.org/en/latest/build.html#building-on-windows

Comment: да нет, VS 13, всё как на хабре. Тогда у меня просьба к Вам, написать подробней, что же всё таки нужно делать. Прямо по пунктам. Чтобы человек, только узнавший что такое python и гит, мог установить без проблем. Это было бы действительно здорово.

Comment: Эх, знать бы, на каком этапе у Вас возникла сложность. Расписывать инструкцию можно сколь угодно подробно, но на это требуется сколь угодно много времени. Поэтому я дополнил ответ краткой инструкцией. Пожалуйста, сообщите, на каком этапе Вы сталкиваетесь с проблемами.

Comment: В этой инструкции у меня проблемы с git. У меня есть аккаунт на гитхабе, но на компьютере вроде только gitbash(?). Скажите, каким образом кланировать репозиторий и где искать гит shell? Достаточно просто архив с гитхаба скачать? Спасибо за дополнение, конечно.

Comment: Хорошо, ответ дополнен инструкцией о том, как запустить нужную консоль и восстановить к ней ярлык, если тот был почему-то удалён. Желаю успеха!

Comment: @Ilya я пытаюсь запустить cp make/mingw64.mk config.mk; make -j4 на 32 битной системе и мне пишет вот такую ошибку `cc1plus.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
cc1plus.exe: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in
Makefile:97: recipe for target 'build/common/common.o' failed
mingw32-make: *** [build/common/common.o] Error 1`

Comment: Обычно это означает, что используется компилятор, собранный без опции "--enable-multilib" - можно пересобрать. Или надо проверить пути (возможно, в системе у вас есть оба компилятора, но раньше в PATH стоит путь к старому.